# How to compute importance sampling?

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, computational-statistics, importance-sampling

I am trying implement importance sampling of this integral
$$
\mathfrak{I} = \int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\sqrt{\left| \frac{\theta }{1-\theta } \right|}}f(\theta )\text{d}\theta
$$
where $f(\theta )\propto {{(1+{{\theta }^{2}}/5)}^{-3}}$ is a t-distribution with df=5.

I already sampled from the above distribution and was told to use samples from 1 and 2 below:

1. Importance function equal to
   $$
   0.5\{{{g}_{1}}(\theta )+{{g}_{2}}(\theta )\},
   $$
   where 
   $$
   {{g}_{1}}(\theta )=\frac{1}{\pi }\frac{1}{1+{{\theta
       }^{2}}}
   $$ 
   and
   $$
   {{g}_{2}}(\theta )=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{\left|1-\theta
       \right| }} \quad\text{on}\quad\space [0,2]
   $$
2. Importance function equal to 
   $$
   g'(\theta)\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left| 1-\theta  \right|}}\exp (-\left| 1-\theta  \right|)
   $$

How should I do this?  I have searched around, and vaguely understands concept.  Could someone explain more in detail what I should do?  Seems like I have all the tools I need.

Comment: The first suggestion is wrong:  $g_2$ is not defined on the real line. See Example 3.13 of our book [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441919392?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441919392) where this problem is fully processed!

Comment: @Xi'an: wow, you have keen eyes, I missed out typing $for \theta \in [0,2]$.  Actually, I have a general question, in this formula 
$$h(x)=\int{h(x)\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)dx=E\left[ \frac{h(X)f(X)}{g(X)} \right]}$$
$$\simeq \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}{\frac{f\left( {{X}_{j}} \right)}{g\left( {{X}_{j}} \right)}h\left( {{X}_{j}} \right)}$$
Where do you find your $h\left( {{x}_{j}} \right)$ ?

Comment: 1. $\theta\in [0,2]$ still does not work in $\sqrt{1-\theta}$!

Comment: 2. Computing $h(x_j)$ means taking a simulated $x_j$ and applying the function $h$ to this value... What is the problem with this?!

Comment: @Xi'an I am having a hard time applying the formula, what are my h, g, f, functions.  Here's what I think, $$h(x) \text{ is } \sqrt{\left| \frac{\theta }{1-\theta } \right|}$$ 

$$g(x) \text{ is } \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\theta }}\exp \left( -(1-\theta ) \right)$$

$$f(x) \text{ is } (1+ \theta^{2}/5)^{-3}$$

Is this correct?  If so, then say, I am using samples from gamma distribution $$g\left( x \right)\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left| 1-x \right|}}\exp \left(-\left| 1-x \right| \right)$$, do I have to find normalizing constant?

Comment: Note that $g$ is a _folded_ gamma distribution: this means you simulate $X\sim G(1/2,1)$ and then derive $Y=1\pm X$, the sign being chosen uniformly, i.e. with probability $1/2$. Therefore the normalisation constant is simply $1/$ of the usual $G(1/2,1)$ density, $1/\Gamma(1/2)$.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice it is a folded gamma. I did this  $$F(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{*{35}{l}}
   \int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\exp \left( -(1-x) \right)dx} & \text{if x}<1  \\
   \int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\exp \left( -(x-1) \right)}dx & \text{if x}>1  \\
\end{array} \right.$$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}{{e}^{-(1-x)}}}dx=-\int\limits_{1}^{0}{2{{e}^{-{{u}^{2}}}}}=\sqrt{\pi }erf(1)=1.49$$
$$\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\exp \left( -(x-1) \right)}dx=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{2{{e}^{-{{u}^{2}}}}}du=\sqrt{\pi }=1.77$$
1.49+1.77=3.27

Comment: Two things: (a) the first integral should be from $-\infty$ to $0$, in relation to the initial problem (b) the function $F(x)$ does not depend on $x$ since $x$ is integrated out (use two constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ instead).

Comment: Could you let us know where you are stuck on our explanation in Example 3.13 of our book [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441919392?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441919392)?

Comment: I just got a hold of your book today (thanks for the examples, Christian).  In example 3.13, I was stuck on $h_{1}(x)$, $h_{2}(x)$, $h_{3}(x)$.  I haven't read through from the beginning, maybe you mentioned earlier.

Comment: I've also been reading your other book"Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R", pretty good examples, I find it very practical for learning.

Answer (score 5):

In case your difficulty is with the simulation *per se*, here is my R code to compare simulations from $f$ (plain), $g$ equal to
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathbb{I}_{[0,2]}(x)}{\sqrt{|1-x|}}
$$
(mixture of Cauchy and power distributions) and $m$ equal to
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|1-x|}}\exp\{-|1-x|\}
$$
(folded Gamma).

Simulating from $f$ is straightforward

```
> sam1=matrix(rt(10^6,df=5),ncol=100)
> fam1=h(sam1)
```

where

```
> h
function(x){ 
sqrt(abs(x/{1-x}))}
```

Simulating from $g$ requires simulating from the square-root part. If you integrate out $1/4{\sqrt{|1-x|}}$ over $[0,2]$, you get either $1-\sqrt{1-x}$ over $[0,1]$ or $\sqrt{x-1}$ over $[1,2]$, which means that this distribution can be represented as 
$$
1\pm \mathcal{U}(0,1)^2.
$$
(In the following, I force both subsamples to have the same size $5\cdot10^5$, which is a Rao-Blackwellisation trick to reduce the variance with no impact on the expectation.)

```
> sam22=1+sample(c(-1,1),5*10^5,rep=TRUE)*runif(5*10^5)^2
> sam21=rcauchy(5*10^5)
> sam2=matrix(sample(c(sam21,sam22)),ncol=100)
> fam2=h(sam2)*dt(sam2,df=5)/g(sam2)
```

where

> g=function(x){.5*dcauchy(x)+.125*((x>0)*(x<2))/sqrt(abs(1-x))}

Simulating from $m$ follows from the folded representation:

```
> sam3=matrix(1+sample(c(-1,1),10^6,rep=TRUE)*rgamma(10^6,.5),ncol=100)
> fam3=h(sam3)*dt(sam3,df=5)/(.5*dgamma(abs(1-sam3),.5))
```

The comparison of the three simulation methods is illustrated in the following boxplot (that we should use in the next edition of [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919392)!)

[image: Boxplot of the variations of three estimators of \mathfrak{I}]

Comment: I will run this in R, if I got questions, I'll leave a msg, thanks again!

Comment: Here the definition of `sam3` takes 5 times as many samples as the other tests.  This makes the folded Gamma look better than the Cauchy-power mixture, while the reverse is true.  The folded Gamma estimator has infinite variance, while the Cauchy-power mixture does not.

Comment: Indeed, the mixture does better now. About the infinite variance, we noticed this (major) drawback in [the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919392). However, it does not seem to impact the practical implementation (in that we do not see strange realisations in the range of the estimates)...

Comment: The problems with the variance are akin to the game where you win $2^n/n$ dollars with probability $2^{-n}$.  The expected payout may be infinite, but I am not about to sell my house to play.  With the folded gamma there will be large excursions, but they will be extremely rare.  In practice using $\frac{\sum hf/g}{\sum f/g}$ with the folded gamma performs worse, although in theory it has finite variance.

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry to bother you again, but your definition of `h` contain the t distribution, when it should just have the $\sqrt{|x/(1-x)|}$. This causes all the estimates to be off because you are multiplying by f^2 instead of f.  The approximations should be around 1.015, while they are around 0.25.